# Galaxy S4 not recognized on windows 8.1 device manager

Tags: android, windows

I recently upgraded to windows 8.1 and tried to connect my Galaxy S4. I have installed:

- the Samsung usb drivers
- Kies
- ADT updated with usb drivers installed
- Fully updated windows 8

When I plug the device into the pc nothing whatsoever happens on the pc device manager and the phone says low power charging please use a recommended cable. The cable I'm using is the one that came with the phone and when I used it on a windows xp install everything worked as it should. Furthermore with the device plugged in this is the output from the adb when looking for devices:

```
C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>adb k
ill-server

C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>adb s
tart-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *

C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>adb d
evices
List of devices attached


C:\Users\Ken\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\platform-tools>
```

At this point I'm fairly sure this is a compatibility issue with windows 8.1 and the galaxy usb drivers. However, I have been researching for days with no luck. The android version and model of the phone is 4.3 and SCH-I545 respectively.

Thanks for the help :)

Comment: is the system 32 or 64 bit?

Comment: I've had problems with the Samsumg 64 bit drivers.  I ended up using  Windows MTP driver (for Windows 7:  device manager -> portable devices -> your device -> update driver -> search internet for driver).

Comment: Okay installed the MTP driver and restarted the computer. Still nothing in device manager when the device is plugged in.

Comment: Now that I recall, I think I also had to remove the Samsung drivers first, and reboot. Then install the MTP driver.  Though you might be seeing a different issue on windows 8.   I was using galaxy s4 on win7.

Comment: here are a few links that were useful for me: http://jeffangelini.com/installing-samsung-galaxy-nexus-drivers-on-windows-7-x64  and http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1830108

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I'll check those out, tried the uninstall and still no luck. I'm about to just roll back to windows 7. I've had nothing but problems with windows 8.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error and finally Figured Out what the hell is that:

> ```
> 1. Install Windows Media Player
> 2. Scan for hardware changes in the Device Manager
> ```

Its actually because MTP requires Media Protocol. If you have updated to N and related versions of Windows 8.1, they have removed the Windows Media Player. So, install it to use MTP.
You can do that from:

> 1. Windows Features > Click on Windows Media Player. It will search or Install.
> 2. Install manually from http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/download-windows-media-player

Answer (score 3):

I've had a similar problem to everybody here and could not find a solution.  I finally tried something obvious and use the "Samsung supplied usb cable" instead of some other generic cables.  My S4 was immediately recognized and I am having so problems.

Answer (score 2):

The driver's installation program has compatibility issues, but the driver itself seems to be compatible and is working fine. Try to change compatibility settings of the installation file ("SAMSUNG_USB_Driver_for_Mobile_Phones.exe") to Windows 7. After doing this, I was able to run the installer and successfully install the drivers on my machine. (I used installer version: 1.5.4.0)

Answer (score 2):

As the previous post, if your windows 8, 8,1 is version N or KN Just install

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40744

be sure to check 32 or 64 depending of your windows version
This will solve your problem.
Regards

Comment: You where right. That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need Windows Media Player

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Uninstall the extra usb drivers
2. Use the troubleshooting menu on Kies to re- install the driver
3. Tap 7 times on the build number of your About phone to display the developer options
4. Go to Settings-> Developer option and activate the 'usb debugging', you should be prompted on your device if adb is running.

Comment: Yeah thanks for the tip should have mentioned that I tried that already. Usb debugging is on and drivers re installed multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having the same issues with my Galaxy S3, and after talking to someone at Samsung support, I was eventually told that Samsung has not yet released official Windows 8.1 USB drivers, and that I should wait for those. Have yet to find another workaround.